# Вывод в консоль

Tags: c++

Вывожу много информации в консоль. Заполняется так, что нужно прокручивать. Как узнать сколько строк туда уже выведено?

Comment: Скорее всего только считать непосредственно прямо в программе, сколько Вы вывели.

Comment: Так при переполнении консоль сама того... скроллится.

Comment: @kail: А чего именно вы хотите добиться? Какая ваша настоящая проблема?

Comment: @VladD надо знать ето число

Comment: @VladD манипуляции всякие делать

Comment: @gbg как это связано с моим вопросом?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский надо после вывода

Comment: @kail - прямо связано. Чтобы знать, когда консоль заполнится, нужно знать ее размеры.

А чтобы считать строки при выводе... ну, красивым решением будет навесить на cout свой поток вывода, который будет учитывать все переводы строк (в том числе и разбивку слишком длинных строк).

Короче, вы переизобретаете ncurses

Comment: можете ответить?

Comment: @kail Для какой ОС это надо делать?

Comment: @kff windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку, как стало ясно из комментариев, можно ограничиться ОС Windows, то, возможно, подойдёт следующее решение, основанное на WinAPI:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;

    while (true)
    {
        printf("===\n");

        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsoleOutput, &info);
        printf("(x,y) = (%d, %d)\n", info.dwCursorPosition.X, info.dwCursorPosition.Y);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Программа в бесконечном цикле выводит текущие координаты консольного курсора в системе координат буфера вывода. Если буфер консоли переполнился, то счётчик как бы останавливается. То есть сколько строк выведено узнать не получится, но сколько строк в текущий момент в буфере (!= на экране) узнать можно.